# Topics and LL/token in Mallet change every time

Tags: mallet

Why do I get different keywords and LL/token every time I run topic models in Mallet? Is it normal?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal and expected. Mallet implements a randomized algorithm. Finding the exact optimal best topic model for a collection is computationally intractable, but it's much easier to find one of countless "pretty good" solutions.

As an intuition, imagine shaking a box of sand. The smaller particles will sift towards one side, and the larger particles towards the other. That's *way* easier than trying to sort them by hand. You won't get the exact order, but each time you'll get one of a large number of equally good approximate sortings.

If you want to have a stronger guarantee of local optimality, add `--num-icm-iterations 100` to switch from sampling to choosing the single best allocation for each token, given all the others.

Comment: Thanks. May I know what is the icm? What is the difference between --num-icm-iterations 100 and --num-iterations 100?

Comment: it stands for "iterated conditional modes", which probably doesn't help! The difference is as I described it: Given all other tokens' current topic assignment, you can get a distribution over topics for one token. Usually we pick a random topic according to that distribution, in ICM we pick the single most probable.